# I cant able to remove a row from a table while running through a loop

Tags: vb.net

I am iterating through the table rows . if the row row is null I just want to remove the row. 
it shows an error

```
 Public Sub RemoveBlankRow(ByVal MyDataTable As DataTable)
        Try
            Dim MyRowStr As String = String.Empty
            For Each MyRow As DataRow In MyDataTable.Rows
                MyRowStr = ""
                For Each MyCellText As Object In MyRow.ItemArray
                    MyRowStr = MyRowStr + MyCellText.ToString
                Next
                MyRowStr = Replace(MyRowStr, "0", " ")
                MyRowStr = Replace(MyRowStr, ".", " ")
                If MyRowStr.Trim = String.Empty Then
                    MyDataTable.Rows.Remove(MyRow)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Just a note: string.Empty is not the same thing as null.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't modify the structure of a collection while you iterate over it.

A simple solution is while iterating over your table, store the rows that need to be deleted in a separate deletion list. When you have finished iterating, iterate over your list of deletions and delete them from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of your `MyDataTable.Rows`, iterate over that and remove the rows from your original collection.